# How to use .cpp and .h files inside subdirectories?

Tags: c++, g++

This is the contents of a directory in my system:

```
/directory/
    classes/
        class1.cpp
        class1.h
    main.cpp
```

And here is the contents of above files:

main.cpp

```
   #include "classes/class1.h"

   int main(){
       class1 test;
       return 0;
   }
```

class1.h

```
   class class1 {
       public:
           class1();
           void test();
   };
```

class1.cpp

```
   #include "class1.h"

   class1::class1(){
   }
   class1::test(){
   }
```

The question is why I can't compile `main.cpp`?

```
ghasemi@ghasemi-MS-7693:~/Desktop/directory$ g++ *.cpp
/tmp/ccEvIogL.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `class1::class1()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your main `directory` there is only one `.cpp` file, and the `*` wildcard doesn't look in sub-directories. You need to explicitly name all the source files, or use multiple wildcards (not something I recommend).

So something like

```
g++ main.cpp classes/class1.cpp
```

Comment: Isn't there anyway to force G++ to search all the subdirectories for `cpp` files?

Comment: @Abraham Not GCC no. If you use a Makefile then it's possible, but I still recommend you explicitly list the source files. Think to the future where you might have multiple projects in your root directory, each project being a separate program. Just blindly getting all source file in all sub-directories will then cause problems.

Comment: @Abraham Use a build system like SCons or CMake.

Comment: You better also tell about linking files together into single binary, this would be also useful in the answer, I think.

Answer (score 1):

What you are searching for is not related to the compiler (gcc) itself but to a build environment. There are several tools which do the job.

If you start with only a hand full of files, you can compile every file every time. But if your projects become bigger it is very time consuming to compile all files again and again, also if nothing has changed in some of them!

Most common for this job is gnu make.

You have to write a configuration which describes your project. This file is typically called "Makefile".

Here you define:
Which files must be compiled if a file changes.
Which files must be linked together.
All parameters for linkage and compile for all or individual files.
... a lot more

So please take a look for https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/

For your project, it can be look like:

```
all: myprog

main.o: main.cpp classes/class1.h

classes/class1.o: classes/class1.cpp classes/class1.h

myprog: main.o classes/class1.o
    g++ main.o classes/class1.o -o myprog
```